# Modify request before submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've got a problem to modify request on a form validation.

I have this entity :

```
class Ad {

    private $id;

    /**
    * @var Entity\Category
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category")
    *
    */
    protected $category;
}
```

For lot of case, I need many *Category*, so I put *ManyToMany* with checbox forms. But in one case, I need a form with only radio button on *Category* to get only one.

So I've created the corresponding FormType :

```
class AdFormType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('category', null, [
            'class' => 'Entity\Category',
            'required' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I do a $form->submit($request), it's failed because it wants *ArrayCollection* instead of *Category* entity.

So I've try to create a listener with ***PRE_SUBMIT*** Event to modify request, but it failed.

```
class AdListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreBind',FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'onPostBind',FormEvents::SUBMIT => 'onBind');
    }

    public function onPreBind(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $data['category'] = [$data['category']];
        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

Have you some ideas to force *ArrayCollection* of *Category* ?

Thanks for helping.

**Bouffe**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is use the [collection field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). There's a great cookbook article on this [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). That's probably the proper way to implement what you're trying to do anyway.